# How to store word translations (one to many)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `LocalTexts` table:

```
id(pk, autoincrement) code |   lang | name
1                      1        ln     Aquastors
2                      1        en     Question
```

Also the table `RateClassificator`:

```
id (pk, autoincrement) idLocalText (fk)
1                      1
```

So, when I want to get all translates for row: `RateClassificator.id` I do:

```
SELECT * FROM RateClassificator 
ON RateClassificator.idLocalTex = LocalTexts.id WHERE LocalTexts.lang == 'ln' 
AND RateClassificator.code = 1;
```

I confues about relation, is it one to many? because one word can have some translates.

Comment: your query confuses me; from your schema it looks like a rateclassificator row only has one localtexts, so only one lang.  so I don't see how "get all translates for row" with id 1 makes any sense, especially if you then also have a `lang = 'ln'` condition.  maybe provide more data better showing how your schema works?  is there any key in localtext that ties together different translations of the same word?

Comment: I have updated the questions, check out

Comment: But I am not sure in code field

Comment: could you edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table RateClassificator;` and `show create table LocalTexts;`?

Comment: ah, from your comment to the answer, it sounds like this is a schema you are designing, not an existing schema you are trying to work with?  if so, and you want advice on the schema, not just a query, please do update your question to indicate that

Comment: Updated...I edited a title of question

Answer (score 0):

It is one to many indeed,
A RateClassification can only have one LocalText
and a LocalText can be assigned to more than one RateClassification.

If for example RateClassification id 2 also has LocalText 1 then 2 RateClassifications have the same LocalText.

I believe what is missing in your querie is a NATURAL JOIN between the two tables.

Comment: a join, but very unlikely a natural join

Comment: Could you share own experience how to store all translates of word? And use it word in different tables?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably have 2 tables, one with English word and another table with translations.

```
tbl_en
ID(auto increment)         name
         1               Question

tbl_trans
ID(auto increment)          en_ID(foreign key)       name          lang
       1                           1               Aquastors        ln
       2                           1               Preguntas        es
```

This is one to many relationship.